# Testing Angular 1.x Component using ES6 doesn't load bindings using $componentController

Tags: angularjs, testing, ecmascript-6, components

I have the following code

**My component**

```
class PaginationController{
    page = 1

    constructor() {
        console.log(this) // PaginationController {page: 1}
    }
}
export const PaginationComponent = {
  templateUrl: '/components/app/views/pagination.html',
  controller: PaginationController,
  controllerAs: '$ctrl',
  bindings: {
      data: '=',
      size: '<',
  }
}
```

**Test**

```
import { PaginationComponent } from '../src/components/app/pagination'

describe("Pagination Controller", () => {

    let controller

    beforeEach(() => {
        angular
          .module("Test", [])
          .component('pagination', PaginationComponent)
    })

    beforeEach(window.module("Test"))

    beforeEach(inject(($componentController) => {
        controller = $componentController('pagination', null, {
            data: [],
            size: 10
        })
    }))

    it("change page", () => {
        console.log(controller)
    })
})
```

I expect that the console.log on the contructor in the controller prints `PaginationController {page: 1, data: [], size: 10}` but i get `PaginationController {page: 1}`, so i assume that the binding is not working.

**Anybody can help me to understand why?**

Answer (score 0):

Finally this work executing the `.contructor()` explicitily like this:

```
beforeEach(inject(($componentController) => {
    controller = $componentController('pagination', null, {
        data: [],
        size: 10
    })
    controller.constructor()
}))
```

The problem here is that the `.constructor` method it's called two times:
The first time is when the `$componentController` it's executed and at this time, the bindings aren't available in contructor method, but if i execute `controller.constructor()` the binding are availables. So, i'm still without understand why.